# Print and file.write giving different outputs, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
message = 'aaa'
for alpha in message:
   num = ord(alpha) + 2
   ans = chr(num)
   print(ans)
   file = open('f.txt', 'w')
   file.write(ans)
   file.close()
```

`print(ans)` prints ccc as expected, but `file.write(ans)` writes only 'c'. How come it doesn't print the entire string? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` method starts to write from a certain (current) position in a file. Since you open the file on every iteration, write will always start from the beginning of the file, overwriting the existing data. In your case it will replace the existing letter *c*.

You'll need to open the file *before* the loop and close it *after* the loop. This will make the file retain the position (check that with `file.tell()`):

```
message = "aaa"
file = open('f.txt', 'w')
for alpha in message:
   num = ord(alpha) + 2
   ans = chr(num)
   print(ans)
   file.write(ans)

file.close()
```

Or, even better, use a context manager:

```
message = "aaa"
with open('f.txt', 'w') as file:
    for alpha in message:
        num = ord(alpha) + 2
        ans = chr(num)
        print(ans)
        file.write(ans)
```

Comment: Holy crap that worked. Thanks a lot. Could you do me a favor and explain why exactly that works?